# Postgres event trigger gives "ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in"

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, eventtrigger

I need an event trigger that gives CRUD access to a particular user each time a schema is created.

Here is my attempt:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_after_create_schema()
RETURNS event_trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA TG_TABLE_SCHEMA TO "api_server";
  GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA TG_TABLE_SCHEMA TO "api_server";
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER after_create_schema
ON ddl_command_end
WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE SCHEMA')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_after_create_schema();
```

This results in the following error:

```
ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in    
SQL state: 3F000
```

I am executing this in `pgAdmin` as a superuser, so I don't think it's a permission issue.

What am I missing?

### Edit

The `CREATE SCHEMA` statement looks something like this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA "tenant" AUTHORIZATION "auth_server";
```

Where `auth_server` is a non-superuser with create schema privileges.

As a workaround I could give `auth_server` the `CREATEROLE` privilege and execute the `GRANT` statement in the same transaction as the `CREATE SCHEMA`, but this seems sub-optimal to me.

`auth_server` doesn't need `CREATEROLE` outside of this scenario, and it would also require hacking source code of a third party package, ie. [`django_tenants`](https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants).

Answer (score 1):

Grants cannot be run directly in a procedure/function, you need dynamic SQL. Try:

```
create or replace 
function trigger_after_create_schema()
 returns event_trigger 
language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
   k_grant_usage constant text = 
     'grant usage on schema % to "api_server"'; 
   k_grant_dml   constant text = 
     'grant select, insert, update, delete on all tables in schema tg_table_schema to "api_server"'; 
      
   l_ddl_stmt text;
begin
   l_ddl_stmt = format(k_grant_usage,tg_table_schema);
   raise notice 'Running statement: %',l_ddl_stmt; 
   execute l_ddl_stmt; 
  
   l_ddl_stmt = format(k_grant_dml,tg_table_schema);
   raise notice 'Running statement: %',l_ddl_stmt; 
   execute  l_ddl_stmt; 
end;
$$;
```

However, the error message you are getting in NOT in the trigger. It indicates the **CREATE SCHEMA...** command in invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately, I still get the exact same error

Comment: What is your actual CREATE schema statement. Try this. Drop that trigger. Then rerun your create. What is that result?

Comment: I never actually ran the create sql, and the trigger was never created. The error happens when I try to create the trigger, not when I run `CREATE SCHEMA`.

Comment: Also, I'm using [`django_tenants`](https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants) to create schemas and manage connections, so I don't have the exact create statement.  Give me a second and I'll add an example

Comment: I could run your create trigger in pgAdmin4, DBeaver, and psql. All successfully. This leads me to believe there is something 'unseen' in your statement. Try completely deleting and reentering it. BTW I have 0 knowledge of django anything so I am no help there.